# FlowLayoutPanel not showing more than one Control after it's cleared

Tags: vb.net, winforms, controls, flowlayoutpanel

My program automates a process on a website using selenium, HTTP requests, and an HTML parser known as HtmlAgilityPack.

There are parts of this process that require user input that can not be automatically filled out by hard-coded values. Allowing the user control over the website to fill in these inputs would be a mistake. It would be difficult to know when they are done inputting it and they would likely touch something they shouldn't which would cause errors when control of the website is handed back over to the program.

Instead, I download the page source of the website using selenium and parse the inputs out of the HTML with HtmlAgilityPack. Then controls matching those inputs are dynamically generated and added to a FlowLayoutPanel. The FlowLayoutPanel works correctly the first time. It displays all added controls. When the user is done they click on a button and the process continues.

Sometimes the process encounters errors that cause it to loop back to where the user needs to enter input again. The exact code that worked before is then run in the same subroutine again. It all runs without error and as expected. I have manually checked at runtime that the controls are added to the FlowLayoutPanel, that they have a size bigger than 0, 0, and that they are a visible color. Yet only one control ever shows up in the FlowLayoutPanel no matter how many should be visible.

The FlowLayoutPanel has it's `AutoScroll` property set to `true` and it has adequate space to add more controls.  As I said this works fine the first time around just not the second. I've been stuck on this for a while and would appreciate some help. The code is going to be posted below for you to look at.

The code I am going to post has several FlowLayoutPanels. One that is on the Form permanently that was created in the designer and the others are generated dynamically to group up the controls.

The issue is with the permanent one. It shows one control as I said. This control is the first dynamically generated flow layout panel and all of it's children. It doesn't display any of the other FlowLayoutPanel controls that are added to it. Just whichever one is added first.

For those of you wondering about the line `FLPOutOfStock.ImprovedClear()` in the code bellow, The .Improved clear is an extension method I wrote. When Clearing the FlowLayoutPanel with the normal method, `.Clear()`, the controls get removed but they don't get disposed of. My method disposes of all the controls in the panel and then calls the `Clear()` method on the panel.

I realize that the `Clear()` method isn't necessary after they've been disposed of it's just a backup since nothing ever seems to work. I wanted to make sure the panel was fully reset.

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub UIOutOfStockState_Load()
    Try
        cmdOutOfStockDeleteAll.Enabled = False
        cmdOutOfStockContinue.Enabled = False
        FLPOutOfStock.ImprovedClear() 'The flowlayoutpanel that does not display all controls
        With New WebDriverWait(ChromeDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(Function(driver) CBool((CType(driver, IJavaScriptExecutor)).ExecuteScript("return jQuery.active == 0")))
        End With
        LBLOutOfStockErrors.Text = "Notice. The following items are out of stock. Please see below for product-specific availability dates. If you have any questions, please contact Customer Service at (800) 843-2020. All direct to patient orders will ship complete. The entire order will ship when out-of-stock product becomes available."
        Dim OutOfStockDoc As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
        OutOfStockDoc.LoadHtml(ChromeDriver.PageSource)
        Dim OutOfStockProductNodes As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection = OutOfStockDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[contains(@id,'id_detail_item_')]")
        FLPOutOfStock.SuspendLayout()
        If OutOfStockProductNodes IsNot Nothing Then
            For Each OutOfStockProductNode As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode In OutOfStockProductNodes
                Dim FLPOutOfStockProduct As New FlowLayoutPanel
                FLPOutOfStockProduct.SuspendLayout()
                FLPOutOfStockProduct.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.LeftToRight
                FLPOutOfStockProduct.AutoSize = False
                FLPOutOfStockProduct.Size = New Size(420, 160)
                FLPOutOfStock.Controls.Add(FLPOutOfStockProduct)
                Dim WBProductText As New WebBrowser
                WBProductText.Size = New Size(400, 120)
                WBProductText.AllowNavigation = False
                WBProductText.AllowWebBrowserDrop = False
                WBProductText.IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled = False
                WBProductText.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True
                WBProductText.ScrollBarsEnabled = True
                WBProductText.Margin = New Padding(0, 0, 0, 0)
                WBProductText.Padding = New Padding(0, 0, 0, 0)
                WBProductText.Navigate("about:blank")
                Dim ProductTextHtmlDoc As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
                ProductTextHtmlDoc.LoadHtml(OutOfStockProductNode.OuterHtml)
                ProductTextHtmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/descendant::a[@id='patient-outOfStock-delete-item']").Remove()
                WBProductText.DocumentText = ProductTextHtmlDoc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml
                FLPOutOfStockProduct.Controls.Add(WBProductText)
                FLPOutOfStockProduct.SetFlowBreak(WBProductText, True)
                Dim SpaceReducer0 As New Panel
                SpaceReducer0.Size = New Size(0, 0)
                FLPOutOfStockProduct.Controls.Add(SpaceReducer0)
                Dim cmdProductDeleteButton As New Button
                cmdProductDeleteButton.Text = "Delete"
                cmdProductDeleteButton.BackColor = Color.White
                cmdProductDeleteButton.ForeColor = Color.Black
                cmdProductDeleteButton.Margin = New Padding(0, 0, 0, 0)
                cmdProductDeleteButton.Padding = New Padding(0, 0, 0, 0)
                cmdProductDeleteButton.Size = New Size(400, 20)
                Dim OnClickAttributeValueWithQuoteEscaping As String = OutOfStockProductNode.SelectSingleNode("/descendant::a[@id='patient-outOfStock-delete-item']").GetAttributeValue("onclick", "")
                cmdProductDeleteButton.Tag = "//a[@id='patient-outOfStock-delete-item' and (@onclick=""" & OnClickAttributeValueWithQuoteEscaping & """)]"
                AddHandler cmdProductDeleteButton.Click, AddressOf cmdProductDeleteButton_Click
                FLPOutOfStockProduct.Controls.Add(cmdProductDeleteButton)
                FLPOutOfStockProduct.SetFlowBreak(cmdProductDeleteButton, True)
                Dim SpaceReducer1 As New Panel
                SpaceReducer1.Size = New Size(0, 0)
                FLPOutOfStockProduct.Controls.Add(SpaceReducer1)
                FLPOutOfStockProduct.ResumeLayout()
            Next
            FLPOutOfStock.ResumeLayout()
            FLPOutOfStock.Refresh()
        End If
        cmdOutOfStockDeleteAll.Enabled = True
        cmdOutOfStockContinue.Enabled = True
    Catch Ex As Exception
        cmdOutOfStockDeleteAll.Enabled = True
        cmdOutOfStockContinue.Enabled = True
    End Try
End Sub
```

So I’ve been asked to show what is in the improved clear method. Here it is:

```
<Extension()>
Public Function ImprovedClear(ByRef Control as Control)
    For Each controlchild as control in control.controls
        Control.Dispose()
    Next
    Control.Controls.Clear()
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Also for those of you wondering about the set flow break and adding the space reducer panels with a size of 0, 0 it is because the flow layout panel doesn't arrange controls in the direction I want if there is more available space in another direction. Say for example flow direction is set to top down. It will layout controls top down until it runs out of vertical space. After this instead of adding scroll bars it will add a new column. To avoid this I set the flow direction to the opposite direction I want. And Use set flow break to make it so it can't add anymore controls in that direction.

Comment: After set flow break is used a invisible space in that direction is added equal to the size of the control that is directly after the one that has flow break set to true. So Adding a control with a size of 0, 0 removes this gap.

Comment: Can you show your implementation of `FLPOutOfStock.ImprovedClear()`? ++ I suggest to build an UserControl that contains the parts you're adding to the inner `FlowLayoutPanel`. Much easier to handle, no need of *fake separators* (this is not a HTML page and doesn't work the same way).

Comment: I made the changes @jimi requested

Comment: Well, as expected. This is wrong: `For Each controlchild as control in control.controls Control.Dispose() Next`, you're disposing of half of the Controls. Use a backwards `For` loop.